# How can I process some Typescript files and copy them along with HTML files, to be included in an Angular project?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

Alongside my Angular project, I have a folder with some HTML and Typescript that I want included into the final `/dist` build of Angular.

I've got `custom-webpack` set up in `angular.json`, so it will run webpack whenever it runs an Angular build.

```
"customWebpackConfig": {
      "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js"
}
```

**The trouble is, I don't know what to put in webpack.**

I want webpack to include the folder `extra-page` in the `dist`, but with all of `extra-page`'s Typescript compiled to Javascript

This is the file structure

```
- src
   |--- app
   |--- assets
   |--- ...
- extra-page
   |--- page1.html
   |--- page2.html
   |--- script1.ts
   |--- script2.ts 
angular.json
custom-webpack.js
...
```

Here is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Comment: https://thecodemon.com/angular-how-to-move-copy-folder-files-during-project-build-process/ if it helps.

Comment: That's cool but I'd rather keep it in webpack so that I can `--watch` it

Comment: Is webpack a requirement?

Comment: Yes because Angular already uses it

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use CopyPlugin in your custom webpack config to copy files that you need:

Example:

```
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "source", to: "dist" },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: This is just copying the files, but how does it compile the Typescript?

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using the some configurations, I tried this type of scenario and it worked for me. Here is what I did :

1. set the Output folder in **tsconfig.json** as follows:

   `"outDir": "./dist/<your angular project name>/extra-page"`
2. Include the **extra-page** folder in  **tsconfig.json**

   `"include": [ "./extra-page/**/*.ts" ]`
3. Generally I used **cpy** package to copy files (It copies html and js files also)

   `npm install cpy-cli`
4. From the npm scripts we can do the major work
   For copying  :
   `"cp-js": "cpy extra-page/**.js dist/sample/extra-page -- parents "`
5. Modify **build** script as follows:

   `"build": "ng build && tsc && npm run cp-js"`

Comment: Changing `tsconfig.json` will mess up the rest of my config though won't it?

Comment: @CodyBugstein nah it won't , I created a sample angular app, it didn't messed up. just give a try. If you have some additional config other than the default one. i can look into it

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the `tsc` overrides the Angular build

Comment: can you provide your `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` .

Comment: @downvoter, can you give justification for your action. i tried the solution and its working for me, if its more then there should be something that is missing from the OP details. without the actual reason its not proper to downvote a solution

Comment: @CodyBugstein can you share the files ?

Comment: @CodyBugstein you missed to add two configs of my steps 1 and step 2

Comment: I did try that but it messed up my angular compile

Comment: @CodyBugstein can you join the [discusison](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233874/discussion-on-67815172)